# Is it possible in mongodb that can i backup of database of particular time i mean i want backup of database eg: 8pm - 9pm = 1hour changes only

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Can I take backup of mongo db on every one hours?
But I want that when I take back up so that the changes should be backup within one hours only.
i want those changes in database which is appeared within 1 hours only i do not want to take whole backup again

Comment: you can create backup for 8pm and 9pm daily, and keep both.

Comment: No you do not understand what i am saying i said that i want backup only one hour between 8 t0 9 .

Comment: i want those changes in database which is appeared within 1 hours only i do not want to take whole backup again

Comment: you'd probably have to either create a 1 hour audit doc and populate that, or compare the two states of the different backups and use that to determine the changes made

Comment: i want to use mongorestore command to take backup